# Jquery:Registration Number Validation on Keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery

I everyone I have a `text-box`

```
Number : <input type="text" name="Number" placeholder="MH03AH6414" id="txtRegNo" />
<span id="errmsg"></span>
```

The `text-box` must take value like the placeholder input(1st two character alphabet (a-z or A-Z) 2nd two character number (0-9) the 3rd two character alphabet (a-z or A-Z) and last four character number (0-9)

I have tried to do with key-press event and all but not formed properly

```
$("#txtRegNo").keypress(function (e) {
   var dataarray = [];
   var dInput = $(this).val();
   for (var i = 0, charsLength = dInput.length; i < charsLength; i += 1) {
       dataarray .push(dInput.substring(i, i + 1));
   }
   alert(dataarray);
   alert(e.key);
   if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
      $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
          return false
      }
});
```

Please help me.
Thanks in advance

I tried of focusout which now works fine with me but I want to prevent from keyinput

Here is the jsfiddle solution

http://jsfiddle.net/ntywf/2470/

Comment: use regex :- [a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{4}

Comment: how to check on each keypress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out. Modified the function as per requirement

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    Number : <input type="text" name="Number" placeholder="MH03AH6414" id="txtRegNo" />
<span id="errmsg"></span>

<!-- end snippet -->
<script>
$("#txtRegNo").keyup(function (e) {
    $("#errmsg").html('');

       var validstr = '';
       var dInput = $(this).val();
       var numpattern = /^\d+$/;
       var alphapattern = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;

       for (var i = 0; i < dInput.length;i++) {

           if((i==2||i==3||i==6||i==7)){
               if(numpattern.test(dInput[i])){
                   console.log('validnum'+dInput[i]);
                   validstr+= dInput[i];
               }else{
                   $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show();

               }
           }

         if((i==0||i==1||i==4||i==5)){
               if(alphapattern.test(dInput[i])){
                   console.log('validword'+dInput[i]);
                   validstr+= dInput[i];
               }else{
                   $("#errmsg").html("ALpahbets Only").show();

               }
           }

       }

       $(this).val(validstr);
      return false;

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks this one is perfect.